# display contents of PHP Mysql Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Simple question (I think).

I have the below PHP / MySQL script:

```
$risksql="select risk from jobsrisks where job='$job'";
$executerisks=mysql_query($risksql);
$test=mysql_fetch_array($executerisks);
$riskrows=mysql_num_rows($executerisks);
```

I want to print the values of the array (for testing), with code:

```
print_r($test);
```

This produces the below output:

[image]

The query, in php actually outputs 3 records, not just one that is repeated. Any ideas whay I am doing incorrectly? where are the other records and why not in the array? is mysql_fetch_array the correct code to use?

I then want to then use the PHP array in another mysql query:

```
$ids = join(',',$test);   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE risk IN ($ids)";
```

Would this then be correct?

Help is appreciated as always.

Thanks,
R

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: If there was ever a job risk it's using `mysql_query`. This kind of code will eventually get you fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to fetch each row, ie:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}
```

check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

```
$ids = join(',',$test);   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE risk IN ('$ids')";
```

almost right. don't forget about quotes

Comment: Quotes don't matter. SQL escaping does.

Comment: $ids = join(',',$test);   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE risk IN ($ids)"; 

- in first it won't work because of <'>; 
- and yes, you are right; there must be escaping, like mysql_real_escape.

And even more, it is better to use PDO. to be more secure, if for some reason PDO is not an option, at least use mysqli drive instead of mysql;

Answer (score 0):

why not join the selects?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE risk IN (SELECT risk FROM jobsrisks WHERE job='$job')";
```